# 2d collisions not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

Working on a platformer game.

For example, collision without logic will overlap each other when you give velocity to one of them (I solve it with triggers that prevent movement to side where other collider is near).

Now I face an unsolvable trouble. Sometimes my character gets stuck in walls

[image]

or cant fall because unseen collision happens.

[image]

1 - box collider

[image]

4 - box collider

[image]

2,3 - triggers

Searching haven't give me structured and right answer, so please, help me solve it.

P.S. Character controller script - https://github.com/rincew1nd/Sleepy-mole/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/character_controller.cs

P.S.S. When I turn off "fixed angle" on character rigidbody2d, all works fine, but physics change a lot and I wanna rigidbody2d with "fixed angle".

Comment: P.S.S. Character controller script. https://github.com/rincew1nd/Sleepy-mole/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/character_controller.cs

Comment: 1 - box collider (http://i.imgur.com/k07eJNc.png) 4 - box collider (https://i.imgur.com/WrHWdOw.png)

Comment: You can edit those images into your post. It will be much easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: You should also post your code. The more info you provide the easier people can help you.

Comment: I can't paste more than 2 links into post, so I post more links in comments. First - code, second - settings. And I find temporary solution. Turn on/off fixed angle of rigidbody2d if position not changed for x sec and character in air.

Comment: I'll upvote you since your question does have potential. Then you can edit the images and links correctly. Also make sure that you paste the code instead of posting a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have find an **temporary** solution for this issue, but it like "invent a wheel", so i still need better solution. Turn on/off fixed angle of rigidbody2d if position not changed for a while and character is not grounded.
http://pastebin.com/Qsm4HACj